# Express session not saving on node16

Tags: node.js, express

I work on a rather large webapp and it built using **node12**, **express**, and **postgres**. We're using the **express-session** middleware for saving sessions in our database. We're in the process of upgrading to **node16**. We've rebuilt a few of our modules using **node16** and tried to run our application, but the server isn't responding to any requests. We've isolated the issue to the first time we invoke `request.session.save()`. What we're seeing is that the `callback` parameter passed to `save` is never invoked suggesting the `save` never completed. It's so odd. Any thoughts? Nothing else has changed.

Comment: It's not very likely that people can help without seeing the relevant code.  If you're using a database store with express-session, then that code would be the likely place to look and part of the relevant code to see.  You could, in fact, just step through `request.session.save()` in the debugger and follow along exactly what its doing.

Comment: I have 2 Intellij run configuration setup that startup my server locally. They both use the same working directory. The only difference is the version of node they use.
- Run config #1 uses node v12.22.12, application works great.
- Run config #2 uses node v16.14.2, application hangs on `req.session.save()`

Comment: As I've already said, you probably have an issue with the session store you're using.  You will need to debug that, research compatibility issues with it, etc...  What exact NPM module are you using for your session store?

Answer (score 0):

We determined the underlying cause was in the implementation of the session store. It was using a very old version of **pg**. Updating to the latest version has addressed this issue. For reference, https://node-postgres.com/